# Windows IoT Web Browser

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2017, windows-iot-core-10

I want to setup my raspberry pi 3 that is running Windows 10 IoT to display a webpage, specifically [this page](https://dakboard.com). My issue is, that looking at IoTBrowser sample code, and I can't figure out how to remove the buttons and address bar and get the webpage to autoload. So I'm asking if anyone has code I can use for it?

The instructions I was trying to follow for removing all the display elements except for the webpage its self can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=120778), but it really confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My issue is, that looking at IoTBrowser sample code, and I can't
>   figure out how to remove the buttons and address bar and get the
>   webpage to autoload.

You can remove all buttons and address bar except `webView` in xaml and utilize `OnNavigatedTo` method to achieve autoload purpose. Then what you need are a few lines code like this:

In MainPage.xaml :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="webView"/>
</Grid>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var address = "https://www.windowsondevices.com";
        webView.Navigate(new Uri(address));
    }
```

Comment: I'll give this a try in about an hour or so, if it's what I'm looking for I'll tick the ✓

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!. I really appreciate it.